# Does Ubuntu 10.10 work well on mac mini?

Tags: 10.10, mac, mac-mini

Does Ubuntu 10.10 work well on mac mini? Are there any known issues?

Comment: PowerPC or Intel Mac mini?

Comment: The most recent one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two pages may help you:

- [Mac Mini Intel Core Duo (3,1) on Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mac_mini3-1/Maverick)
- [Mac Mini 4,1 Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Macmini4-1/Maverick)